# ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack - When reading GRAYSCALE

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am reading an image from a string like this. I know the image is in GrayScale.

```
nparr = np.fromstring(image_string, np.uint8)
roi = cv2.imdecode(nparr,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

But I am getting an error when I get the `shape` of the image

```
h,w,d = roi.shape #gives error
```

The error I get is:

```
    h, w, d = roi.shape
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

If I change `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` to `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` then I don't get the error but I believe doing this changes my image slightly because I get different results when I do further processing on it.

Comment: What is the value of `roi.shape`?

Comment: Is a tuple with two values, but you are expecting three. Try `h,w = roi.shape`.

Comment: But when I read the value as `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` I get `(222,1008,3)`

Comment: If you [look here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) it seems that the difference is normal: color use 3 channel BGR instead grayscale is single channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roi.shape` has only two values.

```
nparr = np.fromstring(image_string, np.uint8)
roi = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = roi.shape
```

[External reference](https://github.com/bgshih/crnn/blob/master/tool/create_dataset.py#L11-L12)